# SQL SELECT DATE Between

Tags: sql, mysql, date

I started to `SET` my dates to `(%d. %M %Y)`.

But now I cant find them with:

`SELECT value FROM _data  WHERE dates >= "01. October 2012" AND <= "01. December 2016"`

The default `DATE_FORMAT` was `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.000` before the `UPDATE` comand.

Can someone explain whats the problem here?

I tried the it with `LIKE '%<date>%'` but it changed nothing.

Comment: Please publish the _data table definition and sample data. You appear to have updated to a non date datatype and your query is attempting a not very useful string comparison

Answer (score 2):

Use STR_TO_DATE to convert dates to a proper format.

```
SELECT value FROM _data
WHERE dates >= STR_TO_DATE('01. October 2012', '%d. %M %Y')
AND dates <= STR_TO_DATE('01. December 2016', '%d. %M %Y');
```

Comment: it doesnt find any data. But there are definately dates between those years.

Comment: Does it throw any error? If yes, post the error here. If not, there might not be any valid data satisfying the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Use yyyy-MM-dd format which is independent of date settings:

```
select value from _data where dates between '2012-10-01' and '2016-12-01';
```

EDIT: A date is a date and %d %M %Y is just a display format. Underlying data is still a date. You shouldn't fall into a mistake like storing them as string.

Here is a [DBFiddle demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/Gg4LgijL)

Comment: Incorrect datetime value: '11 February 2016'  I kinda can't re-set the DATE_FORMAT. EVen when i removed the point.

Comment: @blaert, what do you mean? A date is a date. %d %M %Y is just a display format and it is still a date. Check edited answer and if it is not what you meant provide sample data and desired output (if you meant you are now saving all dates as string then you are shooting yourself in the foot).

Answer (score 0):

1. `"01. October 2012"` is a column name in SQL, because of the double quotes. MySQL allows these for strings, too, but you should always use single quotes for string literals.
2. So, `'01. October 2012'` is a string. It starts with the characters '0' then '1' then '.' then ' ' then 'O'. This comes after `'01. April 2023'` for instance, because 'A' < 'O'. This is not at all what you want. You don't want to work with strings. You want to deal with dates.
3. A date literal in SQL starts with the word `DATE` followed by a string in the format 'yyyy-mmdd'.
4. Often we don't only deal with dates, but also with datetimes / timestamps. To play safe we often use `>= startdate` and `< enddate + 1` for date ranges.
5. One of your conditions is `AND <= "01. December 2016"`. This is not a condition. You forgot to tell the DBMS which column shall be less or equal the string literal.
6. Of course, dates should be stored as `DATE`, not as strings. If your table column is a string type, this should be fixed first.

The query you finally want should then be:

```
SELECT value
FROM _data
WHERE dates >= DATE '2012-10-01'
  AND dates <  DATE '2016-12-02';
```